# Doctrine PHP: Polymorphic Associations

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, polymorphic-associations

I am using [Doctrine PHP ORM 2.0](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/zh).

What I would like to implement, is the following class hierarchy. (Please note that the following code fragment will fail to execute, as it is neither syntactically correct PHP, nor correct usage of Doctrine annotations.)

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Location {}

@Entity
class GeoId {
  @Column(type = "float") $latitude;
  @Column(type = "float") $longitude;

  // this is the part that my question concerns
  @???
  $location; // any subclass of location can go here
}
```

Now, for the subclasses of Location we could take `City`, `State` and `Country`, for example. Or `Adress`, if we want to be very specific. For a little more information on this class hierarchy:

```
class Adress  { $parent; /* of type City, ... some other attributes */ }
class City    { $parent; /* of type State */ }
class State   { $parent; /* of type Country */ }
class Country {}
```

(The above hierarchy would make my answer lean towards a Table-per-Class solution.)

### Questions:

1. Is it possible to have a polymorphic attribute in an entity, and if so, how do I implement it?
2. Which what inheritance strategy could I implement the Location class hierarchy (as seen below), and which strategies are preferred (i.e. MappedSuperclass, Single-Table or Class-Table inheritance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a polymorphic
>   attribute in an entity, and if so, how
>   do I implement it?

Yes, Doctrine 2 supports three different types of inheritance: MappedSuperclass, Single Table and Class Table... as you know.
The [Doctrine Reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) explains how to implement them.

Here is a good article you can read on mapping object inheritance: [Mapping Objects to Relational Databases: O/R Mapping In Detail](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MappingInheritance)

Comment: Note: I have not tested this solution, with Single-Table inheritance, but I think it should work. Obviously, it will fail with a mapped superclass, though surprisingly it doesn't fail up until the point where you want to read from the database - writing to the database works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd need Single- or Class-Table-Inheritance. Because you want to query for the root (Location) you should better use Single Table Inheritance for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Doctrine 2 will do polymorphic associations. There issues with bi-directional associations using `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`, but the simple case works fine.

```
/** @Entity */
class GeoId {
  /** @Column(type = "float") */ 
  private $latitude;
  /** @Column(type = "float") */ 
  private $longitude;

  /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="Location") */ 
  private $location;
}
```